# Powershell to extract SQL returning quotes instead of blanks

Tags: sql, powershell, csv

I have a Powershell script that I'm using to extract data from our SQL database to a csv file. The fields need to match the database this is merging with, so I'm using '' to return blank fields for fields our database doesn't have. The problem is the scope needs these to be blank and PS is returning quotes. How do I get rid of the quotes?

I believe this is the relevant code:

```
$LocaltopRows = "top 10"
$LocalFieldDelimter = "|"
$LocalDNE = "DNEinDB"
$localFileExtension = ".csv"
$LocalNullDate = ""
$folderPath = "\Export"
$LocalLogPath = "\Logs"
$DBServer = "SERVER" 
$DBName = "DB"
$dbCompanyName = "COMPANY"

$TESTFIELD  = "'TEST' as [TEST Text]"
$TESTFIELD2  = "'' as [Blank Code]"

$Connection = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection 
$Connection.ConnectionString ="server=$DBServer;database=$DBName;Connection Timeout=0;trusted_connection=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand   #setting object to use sql commands


$SqlQuery = @"
SELECT $LocaltopRows
    $TESTFIELD2
    ,$TESTFIELD
    FROM [$DBName].[dbo].[$dbCompanyName`$Table] as TEST
"@
```

---

Here's the entire code in case I missed something relevant.

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"

###############################################################################
#### Set Country, Server and Database

$runTest = $true

if( $runTest )
{
    # Testing parameters
    $LocaltopRows = "top 10"
    $LocalFieldDelimter = "|"
    $LocalDNE = "DNEinDB"
    $localFileExtension = ".csv"
    $LocalNullDate = ""
    $folderPath = "\Export"
    $LocalLogPath = "\Logs"
    $DBServer = "DB" 
    $DBName = "DB"
    $dbCompanyName = "COMP"

}
else
{
   
    $LocaltopRows = $global:topRows
    $LocalFieldDelimter = $global:FieldDelimter
    $LocalDNE = $global:DNE
    $LocalNullDate = $global:NullDate
    $localFileExtension  = $global:FileExtension
    $folderPath = $global:ExportPath
    $LocalLogPath = $global:LogPath
    
    $DBServer = $global:SQLServerName
    $DBName = $global:DataBaseName
    $dbCompanyName = $global:CompanyName
}


" "
"----------------------------------------------"
"TEST Export"
"----------------------------------------------"
" "


###############################################################################
#### Set Date Variables 

# date for SQL Query 
$dateQ = Get-Date -Format d
       

# date for writing to text file
$tdate = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
$formatedDate = $tdate.ToString()


###############################################################################
#### Create Log file

# set file name
$fileFilter = "Log_Test_" + $formatedDate
$tfil = $fileFilter + "*"
$fname = $fileFilter + ".txt"


if( !(Test-Path $LogPath) )
{
    New-Item $LogPath -ItemType directory
}


$Lpath = $LogPath + "\$fname"

# if the file already exists, then rename it
if( Test-Path $Lpath)
{
    #"Log File Exists, I will create a backup and make a new one"
    
    $numFiles = (Get-ChildItem $LogPath -Filter $tfil).Count

    $newFileName = $fileFilter + "_0" + $numFiles.ToString() + ".txt"
    
    Rename-Item $Lpath $newFileName

}


Start-Transcript -path $LogPath -append


" "
"----------------------------------------------"
"TEST Assign Export"
"----------------------------------------------"
" "

# required Fields  
$TESTFIELD  = "'TEST' as [TEST Text]"
$TESTFIELD2  = "'' as [Blank Code]"


###############################################################################
#### Create output file

# set file name
$fileFilter = "TEST"# + $formatedDate
$tfil = $fileFilter + "*"
$fname = $fileFilter + $localFileExtension

if( !(Test-Path $folderPath) )
{
    New-Item $folderPath -ItemType directory
}

$fpath = $folderPath + "\$fname"

# if the file already exists, then rename it
if( Test-Path $fpath)
{
    #"File Exists, I will create a backup and make a new one"
    
    $numFiles = (Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Filter $tfil).Count

    $newFileName = $fileFilter + "_0" + $numFiles.ToString() + $localFileExtension
    
    Rename-Item $fpath $newFileName

}

###############################################################################
#### SQL Connection Settings


$Connection = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection 
$Connection.ConnectionString ="server=$DBServer;database=$DBName;Connection Timeout=0;trusted_connection=True"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand   #setting object to use sql commands

### Connect to Database and Run Query


$SqlQuery = @"
SELECT $LocaltopRows
    $TESTFIELD2
    ,$TESTFIELD
    FROM [$DBName].[dbo].[$dbCompanyName`$Table] as TEST
"@



if( $runTest)
{
    " "
    "Number of Records Found: "
    $Connection.open()
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $Connection
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=6000
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $Connection.Close()

    $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -path $fpath -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $LocalFieldDelimter -Encoding UTF8 

     (Get-Content $fpath | Select-Object ) | Set-Content $fpath   
 
}
else
{
    " "
    "Number of Records Found: "
    $Connection.open()
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $Connection
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout=6000
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) #| Out-Null
    $Connection.Close()

    $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv -path $fpath -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $LocalFieldDelimter -Encoding UTF8 

}
```

Here's the result I'm getting versus the result I need:

```
"TEST Text"|"Blank Code"
"TEST"|""
"TEST"|""
"TEST"|""
"TEST"|""
"TEST"|""
"TEST"|""
"TEST"|""
"TEST"|""
"TEST"|""
"TEST"|""

"TEST Text"|"Blank Code"
"TEST"|
"TEST"|
"TEST"|
"TEST"|
"TEST"|
"TEST"|
"TEST"|
"TEST"|
"TEST"|
"TEST"|
```

Comment: `Export-Csv` adds `"` as qualifiers to all field values. If you do `Import-Csv $fpath` you'll see that the value itself is indeed just an empty string

Comment: You could just use `ConvertTo-Csv` and post-process the result with some deft string replacement.

Comment: What is wrong with the quotes? These signify zero-length strings. Most apps that interact with CSVs should handle them.

Comment: Using PowerShell 7, you can get close to this with `Export-Csv -Path $path -NoType -QuoteFields 'TEST Text'`. But there is no parameter that allows for *quote only when value is not empty*.

Comment: @Parfait The problem is the database this is importing to needs these to be blank; at least that's the requirement I'm being told. Otherwise, I agree with you.

Comment: Curious which database would that be? They may have a quote handler argument in your import method.

Comment: @Parfait Not sure. My corporation is taking data from all of our different organizations ERPs and building a Business Intelligence data mine. They're in Spain while I'm in the US, so rather than ask a lot of questions, I thought it would be easier to find a solution. Plus it was good to learn :-)

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thank you. You put me on the right path. I was still using PS 5, but once I upgraded to PS7, I was able to use -UseQuotes AsNeeded and that seems to have given me what I needed. I'm fairly confident that I don't actually need quotes around any data.